# REGEXP_LIKE to Look for a String between Two Strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to get all values that have the string "table1" between UPDATE and SET. In my sample code, I expect to get first and second record. Can you help me with the regexp_like.

```
WITH tbl AS
(

SELECT 'UPDATE table1, table2, table1_abc SET' as col1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'UPDATE table1_xyz, table2 SET' as col1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'UPDATE table3 SET' as col1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (upper(col1), 'UPDATE(*table1*)SET')
```

Hence, I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asterisk in regex applies to the symbol before `*`. In your case that's `(`, which is another *metacharacter*, making your expression illegal.

This should work:

```
WITH tbl AS
(
SELECT 'UPDATE table1, table2, table1_abc SET' as col1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'UPDATE table1_xyz, table2 SET' as col1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'UPDATE table3 SET' as col1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col1, 'UPDATE.*table1.*SET', 'i')
```

Note that passing `'i'` as the third parameter is simpler than using `upper(col1)` to get a case-insensitive match, because you do not need to convert the content of your regex to upper case.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/5274)